# Davinci Resolve - Store Clips Edited in Cut Window in a Media Folder

Tags: video, editing, davinci-resolve, workflow, media

I am working on a video project in DaVinci Resolve. It a short video documenting a piece of installation art. One of the media files is a handheld camera that takes close up shots of different parts of the piece. I'm trying to edit this into closeups of individual elements that I can cut to throughout the video.

I'm currently editing the clip in the cut view, but keeping organized is very difficult. I'm looking for functionality where I can drag the clips I've edited into a folder where they can visually be viewed side by side, rather than having them just sit on the timeline, which is a really inefficient workflow. Does this functionality exist and how do I do that?

I'd like to take clips from the cut view that look like this:

[image: Cut View Clips]

And drag them into a folder so I can view and work with them like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of resolve 16.2, it’s not possible to organize media from the cut page that way. Switch to the edit page. All of the edits you’ve made will persist, and you’ll be able to drag timeline clips to bins from there (this creates subclips).  You can then switch back to the cut page and continue to work if that's what you prefer.